# Which is correct in this sentence, I or Me

Tags: grammar

"...illustrates another philosophical divide between you and [I/me]." I'm currently in an argument with a friend about this little bit here. Which is the correct pronoun for this sentance, "me" or "I"?

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/between see the __Usage__ section.

Answer (score 2):

You would say "between us," not "between we," so "between you and me" is correct.